# Datagrid populates with data if tab has not been in focus

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, tabs

I have a weird situation here. While I am digging into trying to figure out why it is happening I thought I might throw it out to the SO community for insight.

I have a wpf form with various tabs. Some of these tabs have tabs. On one of the tabs that is two tabs deep I have a datagrid that is bound to a datatable.

I have observed that if I take the proper actions to populate that datagrid with data before the tab with that datagrid has been focused, then it will contain data. However, if that tab has ever been focused before I populate the datagrid with data, then it will not have data.

Thoughts?

**UPDATE**
I have discovered that rows are making it to the datagrid but each row is really thin and only has one column . . . maybe this is a column generation problem? I do have AutoGenerateColumns="TRUE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did have to do with AutoGenerateColumns="TRUE". I went ahead and populuated the datatable with an empty dataset upon initialization.